# Signature of a bilinearform

Tags: linear-algebra, bilinear-form

I have to determine the signature of the following matrix:

$$ A=
\begin{pmatrix}
5&5&0\\
5&-8&-2\\
0&-2&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The bilinear form $<,>: V \times V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $(x,y)\rightarrow x^tAy$

a.) Determine the signature of the symmetrical bilinear form.

I'm not really sure how to do it. I first tried to calculate the upper triangular matrix:

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
5&5&0\\
5&-8&-2\\
0&-2&0
\end{pmatrix} \rightarrow 
\begin{pmatrix}
5&5&0\\
0& 13& 2\\
0& 0&4 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Since all the eigenvalues are positve ($\lambda_1=5, \lambda_2 = 13$ and $\lambda_3 = 4)$ does it mean that the signature is also positive? Is (3,0) the signature? (3 positve and o negative eigenvalues)?

If not, how do I determine the signature of a matrix?

Comment: What is your definition of the signature?

Comment: Since $\det(A)<0$ we can't have three positive eigenvalues.

Comment: How did you obtain the last form?

Comment: Elementary row operations don’t preserve eigenvalues (they don’t even preserve the determinant, although the affect it in known ways). If they did, then the only eigenvalue of _every_ invertible matrix would be $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added: "Repeated Completing the Square" gives the same outcome this time. The only requirement is Sylvester's Law of Inertia, the details could have been different. You begin with $5x^2 - 8 y^2 - 4 y z + 10 xy.$ We take care of two terms with $5(x+y)^2.$ But now we need $-13 y^2 - 4 y z . $ So we take $-13 (y + \frac{2z}{13})^2.$ At the end, we need to add back $\frac{4}{13} z^2.$

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 13 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 &  - 8 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

So, there are two positive and one negative eigenvalue. The actual eigenvalues are approximately -10.0579,   0.2939,   6.7639.

The method, sometimes called "congruence diagonalization"

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 &  - 8 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 &  - 8 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 13 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 &  - 8 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 &  - 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 13 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  - 13 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 4 }{ 13 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
1 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 2 }{ 13 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr} 
5 & 5 & 0 \\ 
5 &  - 8 &  - 2 \\ 
0 &  - 2 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Comment: For these kind of OP we always give our complementary answers! That’s nice :)

Answer (score 1):

By Sylvester since we have that $\det(A)=-20<0$ the signature can be

$$(-,-,-) \quad \text{or} \quad  (+,+,-)$$

but since $\det(5)=5>0$ we have that the signature is $(+,+,-)$.